# Lazily (de-)serialize JSON with EF Core

Tags: c#, json, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I want to write and read JSON data into/from a PostgreSQL database and (de-)serialize them lazily. Please see the following C# types:

```cs
// project: Business
public class Person // shall be persisted with EF Core in the database
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PersonDto? RawData { get; set; }
}

// vendor assembly (via NuGet)
public class PersonDto // input from another system, coming as JSON over the wire
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    // ...a lot of other properties
}

// project: Persistence
public class PersonContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; private set; }
}

// project: Service
public class Handler
{
    private readonly PersonContext _context;

    public Handler(PersonContext context) => _context = context;

    public async Task HandleInputAsync(PersonDto input)
    {
        var person = new Person { Name = input.Name, RawData = input };
        await _context.Persons.AddAsync(person);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

On the database (PostgreSQL), the data should be persisted like this:

| Id (int) | Name (text) | RawData (json) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | { "Name": "Mike", "Age": 33 } |

So I want to store the raw input in a JSON column. I've written a custom converter to do the JSON (de-)serialization. This implementation works, but it has the downside in that the (de-)serialization happens whenever materializing an object from the DB into an EF Core entity. But I only need to access `RawData` on certain occasions, therefore the (de-)serialization is often not necessary (in terms of computation). Furthermore, I want to avoid the unnecessary allocation of `PersonDto` if not necessary.

Now comes my sixty-four-thousand-dollar question: is it possible to do the (de-)serialization only on demand/lazily? Some usage examples from inside my business layer:

```cs
var name = person.Name; // person.RawData has not yet been used and is therefore uninitialized
var rawData = person.RawData; // now the deserialization takes place.
```

I tried the following approach:

```cs
// project: Business
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string? RawData { get; set; }

    public PersonDto GetRawData() => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PersonDto>(RawData);
}
```

That works, but I wouldn't say I like the following facts:

- The `string? RawData` gets loaded from the DB no matter whether `GetRawData()` is called or not → large unneeded `string` in memory
- My business layer has to work with JSON (de-)serialization APIs. From a *Clean Architecture* perspective, I don't like that a high-level component (`Person`) needs to access low-level details like JSON.

So is there any alternative to solve this in EF Core 7?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One approach is to exclude RawData from your `Person` class and have GetRawData() load the raw data for that ID from the database. Depending on your concurrency requirements, you may wish to cache the result. You would need an analogous method SetRawData() to handle any changes.

Comment: Do you have a small example of how I'd do this?

Comment: **friendly ping** @EricJ.